# How to draw a custom BufferGeometry object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have the followin code:

```
geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( position, 3 ) );

geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( color, 4 ) );

geometry.addAttribute('size', new THREE.BufferAttribute(size, 1));

var shape = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('star.png');   

var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( {size: 55,  map: shape , transparent: true} );

particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );

scene.add( particleSystem );
```

I have an image of a pure star without square borders.
But after drawing I see a square with an inserted star in it.
I don't have enough rating for posting a pic.
http://s10.postimg.org/jhyobwwpl/image.png - this is a result.
http://s13.postimg.org/vyf25b8iv/image.png - this is an original star with highlighting.
Original star doesn't have any border and it is white, so I highlighted it to make it visible.

Question: How to draw the star without square shape?

Comment: Try adding `material.alphaTest = 0.5;`. Does that solve you problem?

Comment: @WestLangley, yes. awesome, thanks a lot!